# MongoDB query from Mongoid criteria object

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there a method in Criteria that will print the actual MongoDB query that criteria is generating?

Comment: It should be printed in your development.log :)

Comment: And while I'm running at console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect Mongoid Criteria instance, you will see "selector" which maps (essentially) directly to the MongoDB selector.  However Mongoid Criteria can be chained and are evaluated lazily, so the result of chaining and lazy evaluation is not available until you do an actual DB operation.  So if you want to see the final result, you should look in the appropriate log.  For a test, this is log/test.log, for "rails c" console, this is log/development.log -- this is standard.

Comment: This isn't helpful. I need to print out the query the criteria generates in my console, not parse a log.

Answer (score -1):

Add the Criteria to a Query, and then you can see it with `toString()`.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);
query.toString();
```

Comment: This is not even ruby code, the question is about Mongoid